# From file_put_contents to saved file on server

Tags: php, pdf

I'm using a Google project API to convert HTML to PDF.  Works great and is amazing.  You can get it here if you want:
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

My question is as follows, the plugin does it's magic and I obtain something like this:

```
file_put_contents("nameOfPdf.pdf", $pdf);
```

How do I go from this to saving it to my server?  I'm new to saving info to server, so please detail a bit.

Thanks.

**MORE OF THE CODE HERE**

```
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->set_paper( "a4" , "portrait");
  $dompdf->render();

  $dompdf->stream("xxxxx.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

  $pdf = $dompdf->output();

// You can now write $pdf to disk, store it in a database or stream it
// to the client.

    file_put_contents("xxxxx.pdf", $pdf);
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is? What do you mean by "save to server" exactly, into a file?

Comment: The idea is, the plugin converts the HTML to PDF.  Then I want to save that pdf to my server.  Does that help?  Let me know.

Comment: isn't that line you're showing not already doing that?

Comment: @Pekka - I added some more code.  I hope it helps.

Comment: @Pekka - you are right, it is saving it to my server.  But in that case, how do set the path for where it should be saved and where do I tell the code to NOT display the PDF?  Just save it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage) correctly, you need to remove this line:

```
$dompdf->stream("xxxxx.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

It will then save it to disk without any output.

To specify a path, add it where you show the file name in the `file_put_contents` call.